# Enable hardware virtualization in BIOS?

Tags: virtualization, bios, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am running a FOXCONN AM2+ M61PMV with an AMD Athlon II X2 240 
Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit.

From startup I have hit the <kbd>del</kbd> key and the options for enabling the hardware virtualization are not there.  I have checked the Microsoft tool that says I can run virtual and i have checked SecurAble, that says yes.  But I have an open case w/microsoft (they've been trying for a week [7 tech support people later]) and they're saying that I need to ensure that the hardware is enabled.

Where do I go to see?  Is there another way besides from the startup?

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a look through your [mobo manual](http://www.foxconnsupport.com/download.aspx?models=en-us0000412&category=C000000001&series=en-us0000008&keywords=&sort=Motherboard%20Manual) ([alternate link](http://www.eio.com/p-18564-foxconn-m61pmv-am2am2-nvidia-geforce-6100-micro-atx-amd-motherboard.aspx)) and there is no option in the BIOS for switching on the hardware virtualisation.

Also, the descriptions of the [BIOS updates](http://www.foxconnsupport.com/download.aspx?models=en-us0000412&category=C000000001&series=en-us0000008&keywords=&sort=Motherboard%20Manual) available do not mention anything about adding support for virtualisation.

It looks to me like the mobo unfortunately does not support it.